# 3 htaccess while I'd like to have 1 only (dev, dev2, prod)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm working on my website.

3 environments :

- Production
- Dev on my main computer
- Dev on my laptop

To access my site I have:

- Prod : http://example.com
- Dev1 : http://127.0.0.1/sb5/
- Dev2 : http://127.0.0.1/edsa-sb5/

The prod .htaccess file uses url rewriting like this :

```
RewriteRule ^deconnexion$ /deconnexion.php [L]
```

the dev1 :

```
RewriteRule ^deconnexion$ /sb5/deconnexion.php [L]
```

the dev2 :

```
RewriteRule ^deconnexion$ /edsa-sb5/deconnexion.php [L]
```

That's very boring.
Is there a solution to make it easier like using a var or any other idea ?

Thanks to all those who can help me.

Comment: sure. don't use htaccess. define it in your apache vhost on each environment.

Comment: _"That's very boring"_ - Huh? I've never though of htaccess rules as fun, no matter what they contain. Is there an actual issue here?

Comment: I’d rather be annoyed (less bored) by having systems that are supposed to be largely identical, have such elementary differences in their setup to begin with ... _why?_